# Getting system Mydocument path using C#.net(Web based Application)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am using C#.net(Web based) and  Am trying  to get Mydocument file path using following code

```
    Label1.Text = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") +"\\My Documents\\";
                 or
     Label1.Text = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

while running  using  IDE .i got correct mydocument path . if i host my application i got different path rather getting mydocument path .

Please help me to find solution

Regrads,
ash

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, you're doing it wrong.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: For error log in My documents by using web application

Answer (score 1):

When the application runs on the server the user account under it executes is surely not your local user account.

This is by definition and it's actually ok, you should design your application in a way that it's independent from the name of the execution account on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want the MyDocument path? If you are doing something with the web you should write to a directory you can clean out with a script that is run periodically.

Personally I would recommend something like

```
Server.MapPath("./temp")
```

The above will give you the full path to the "temp" directory inside of where the current aspx page is.